# How to get a list of followers and following from database

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, json

Im OK with databases but this structure stumps me a bit. It's from Michael Hartls tutorial[image]

I am trying to get a json file that will list all the followers and the people they are following in json format so that `['nodes']`  consists of user names and `['links']` consist of the id of firstly the following and also the follower

The problem is that i have no idea how to execute a query on a table that consists of both the follower and the follwing to get this result when they are both from the same table.

Comment: how would you like to see ONE query return all the data? Or TWO. show desired output in a cut and paste (forgetting json for now)

Answer (score 0):

Join once on the followingId and once on the followerId and that will treat it as two "tables" for you in the set.  You can join tona single table as much as you want.